# clear all past activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to add a lock feature to my application from some of the actives, and I want to make sure that if a user presses the lock button, the user won't be able to press back and go to any of the past activities. So a return on the user's phone after lock will take the user to the phone's home.

I tried CLEAR_TOP but this is not doing the trick, any ideas why?

```
    Button lockButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lockButton);
lockButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AccountListActivity.this, LockActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

It would clear the stack only when you are going to relaunch the first activity , but in your case You are launching a new activity .so It would not clear the previous activities.

You can do one thing to implement your requirements -

Create an Interface and implement in all activities.

then when you are going to launch the LockActivity , before that call the delegate of Interface to finish all the activities.

Comment: Hey GDG, could me an example on how to implement an activity inside the interface , and what would be the proper way to finish all of them? (would it be something like finish()?)

Comment: Yes... simple..like ...Class XYZ extends Activity implements FinishNotifer {   public void finishActivity (){finish()}}..If you want precise code ...please let me know..!!

Comment: The thing that gets me confused is how would one calling to finishActivity from one specific listener would close all other activities.

Comment: I don't know how many activities you have ...but this is suitable for 2-3 activities with separate listener for each  ...or you can use broadcast receiver to finish the all activities or using your existing implementation you can relaunch the first activity again with new intent extra ...and finish it and launch new LockActivity.